# how to stop xslt from rendering html markup

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml:

```
<Chapter>
  <Question>Some details in bullet format here <ul><li> point1 </li> <li></li> </ul>
</Question>
</Chapter>
```

My XSLT (version 1.0) has this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Question">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

My output looks like this:

```
"Some details in bullet format here &lt;li&gt; point1 &lt;li&gt;point2&lt;li&gt;"
```

Instead of the intended html bullet points.

Expected result:

Some details in bullet format here

- point1
- point2

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You should provide more information about input xml and your xslt. I tried your fragments and it seems to worked as expected (returns string value of Question element without html tags). Will you please supply expected result as well?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Could you try `<xsl:value-of select="string()" />`?

Comment: I would expect the output to be: "Some details in bullet format here point1" (whitespace may differ). xsl:value-of returns just the concatenated string value and no element names or attributes

Comment: Thanks so far everyone. I've updated the question with the info requested. I've also tried the <xsl:value-of select="string()" /> but hasn't worked either. I can't post the full xml or xslt as it's sensitive info in there. Whatever I try from xsl research on here and the web I always get the markup displayed: "Some details in bullet format here <ul><li> point1 </li> <li>point2</li></ul>". Any more suggestions please?

Comment: Here's my xslt header if that helps:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>...
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

Comment: My output string has been HTML encoded. That's why it's outputting to screen as text instead of actual markup. Is this the expected output of an xslt transform??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" 
                    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Since the markup was being HTML encoded for whatever reason and the disable tag stops that.

More details here: [After trasforming XML in HTML with XSLT, HTML tags get "stripped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843611/after-trasforming-xml-in-html-with-xslt-html-tags-get-stripped)

Comment: xsl:copy-of is the proper fix.

Comment: @EJP - how come? copy-of brings back the tags as well i.e. "<Chapter>
  <Question>Some details in bullet format here <ul><li> point1 </li> <li></li> </ul>
</Question>" . 

value-of - brings back the actual text within the selected element. Which is what I needed. Please explain?

Answer (score 2):

use `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>`

Comment: This didn't work for me since: copy-of brings back the tags as well i.e. "<Chapter> <Question>Some details in bullet format here <ul><li> point1 </li> <li></li> </ul> </Question>" . value-of - brings back the actual text within the selected element. Which is what I needed. Please explain?

Comment: do you not need <ul> <li> tags? xsl:copy-of should be inside xsl:for-each select="Question"